# java IO Exception: Stream Closed

Tags: java, ioexception

This is the code I currently have:

```
public class FileStatus extends Status{
FileWriter writer;
public FileStatus(){
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("status.txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void writeToFile(){
    String file_text= pedStatusText + "     " + gatesStatus + "     " + DrawBridgeStatusText;
    try {
        writer.write(file_text);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Everything works as expected (The file is written to when the writeToFile method is called). However when the writeToFile method is called a second time I get the following error:

```
    java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at FileStatus.writeToFile(FileStatus.java:19)
    at MenuBar$9.actionPerformed(MenuBar.java:115)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at FileStatus.writeToFile(FileStatus.java:19)
    at MenuBar$9.actionPerformed(MenuBar.java:115)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at FileStatus.writeToFile(FileStatus.java:19)
    at MenuBar$9.actionPerformed(MenuBar.java:115)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
```

the file is still written to the second time as expected but it throws this error on the second and future calls to writeToFile(). I am wondering what is causing this error to happen.

Comment: The first line of your stack trace says it all: `java.io.IOException: Stream closed`. You can't close it and then write to it again.

Comment: Please check whether you are writing the flush or write to file code out side of try-with-resources code. Because in this case it becomes hard to find out where we have written close() code.

It looks as if we have not called any close() function, but it is present and we spend lot of time to actually find it out.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're calling `writer.close();` after you've done writing to it. Once a stream is closed, it can not be written to again. Usually, the way I go about implementing this is by moving the close out of the write to method.

```
public void writeToFile(){
    String file_text= pedStatusText + "     " + gatesStatus + "     " + DrawBridgeStatusText;
    try {
        writer.write(file_text);
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And add a method `cleanUp` to close the stream.

```
public void cleanUp() {
     writer.close();
}
```

This means that you have the responsibility to make sure that you're calling `cleanUp` when you're done writing to the file. Failure to do this will result in memory leaks and resource locking.

***EDIT***: You can create a new stream each time you want to write to the file, by moving `writer` into the `writeToFile()` method..

```
 public void writeToFile() {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("status.txt", true);
    // ... Write to the file.

    writer.close();
 }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of calling `write.close()` ? because I would like to have the option of writing to the file multiple times but if it can't be predicted how many times the file will need to be written to I dont see how you would know when to call `write.close()`

Comment: `write.close()` releases the resource on the system. You should do this as soon as possible. One option you've got is to simply open a new stream each time you want to write, and close it each time.. Check my Edit.

Answer (score 6):

You call `writer.close();` in `writeToFile` so the writer has been closed the second time you call `writeToFile`.

Why don't you merge `FileStatus` into `writeToFile`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `write.close()` in `writeToFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are writing the flush or write to file code out side of **try-with-resources** code.
Because in this case it becomes hard to find out where we have written **close()** code.

It looks as if we have not called any **close()** function, but it is present and we spend lot of time to actually find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the close before closing the braces and check for the open function if any exist.

And call the close() after the try block. This may work