# How to fix ioexception stream closed?

Tags: java, stream, bufferedreader, filereader

On start up my program gives me the message java.io.IOException: stream closed. It then opens with limited components.

I understand what a stream closed exception is, I just can't figure out how to fix it, in my case. I would really appreciate some help. (I'm sorry about the big chunk of code, but I am not sure what you need to help me)

```
 try {
    //Defines new file reader and buffered reader
    FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);

    //action code

        try {
        //Finds the line number to see the number of cards in each set
        lnr2= new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\priceadria\\Desktop\\Words_" + strSetName + ".txt")));
        lnr2.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        strLineNumber2 = String.valueOf(lnr2.getLineNumber());
        lineNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(strLineNumber2);

        //Closes the file reader and buffered reader
        br1.close();
        file_to_read.close();

    } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
        strLineNumber2 = "0";
    }           
        //Adds the set name to the set name array
        lblDeckName[row] = new JLabel (strSetName);

        //Adds all buttons that will be used in the layout into a button array
        JButton aryOptions [][] = new JButton [3][lineNumber];

        //Defines and formats the Add Words button
        JButton btnAddWords = new JButton("Add Words"); 
        btnAddWords.setOpaque(false);
        btnAddWords.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnAddWords.setBorder(null);
        btnAddWords.setBorderPainted(false);

        //Defines and formats the Play button
        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
        btnPlay.setOpaque(false);
        btnPlay.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnPlay.setBorder(null);
        btnPlay.setBorderPainted(false);

        //Defines and formats the Delete Set button
        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete Set");
        btnDelete.setOpaque(false);
        btnDelete.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnDelete.setBorder(null);
        btnDelete.setBorderPainted(false); 

        //Adds each button to the array based on the number of sets
        aryOptions [0][row] = btnAddWords;
        aryOptions [1][row] = btnPlay;
        aryOptions [2][row] = btnDelete;

        //Formats the GridBagLayout (Spaces are for formatting purposes)
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(lblDeckName[row],gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("      "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx =2;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel (strSubjectName),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("                   "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel(strLineNumber2),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("             |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(aryOptions[0][row],gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 7;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 8;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(aryOptions[1][row],gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 9;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |  "),gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 10;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(aryOptions[2][row],gbc);

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 11;
        gbc.gridy = row;
        layoutBackground.add(new JLabel("  |"),gbc);




        //Creates an action event for the delete set button
        btnDelete.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
            //Finds the source of the button that was clicked
            String strSource = String.valueOf(a.getSource());
            String strSourceCut1 = strSource.substring(25,30); 

            //Finds the index of the button that was clicked
            String [] aryIndex = strSourceCut1.split(",");
            String strIndex = aryIndex[0];

            try {
                //Defines new file reader and buffered reader                   
                FileReader file_to_read2 = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file_to_read2);

                //Finds the numerical index of the button that was clicked
                int intIndex = Integer.parseInt(strIndex)/16;

                //Creates a counter to count line numbers
                int counter = 0;

                while((br2.readLine()) != null) {

                    counter ++;
                    if(intIndex == 0) { //If the index is the first option the normal try/catch returns null pointer, so a new try/catch had to be created
                        try {
                            //Finds the name of the set based on what button was clicked
                            String chosenDeck2 = br2.readLine();
                            String [] aryDeleteDeck = chosenDeck2.split(",");
                            deleteDeck = aryDeleteDeck[0];

                            //Closes the buffered reader and file reader
                            br2.close();
                            file_to_read2.close();

                            //Creates the path to the file that needs to be deleted
                            Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\priceadria\\Desktop\\Words_" + deleteDeck + ".txt");
                            Files.delete(p2);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }

                    } else if ( counter == intIndex) {
                        //Reads the deck name based on the button that was clicked
                        String chosenDeck2 = br2.readLine();

                        //Splits the deck name from the subject
                        String [] aryDeleteDeck = chosenDeck2.split(",");            
                        deleteDeck = aryDeleteDeck[0];

                        //Closes the buffered reader and file reader
                        br2.close();
                        file_to_read2.close();

                        //Gets the file that needs to be deleted
                        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\priceadria\\Desktop\\Words_" + deleteDeck + ".txt");
                        Files.delete(p1);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HeadlessException | IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        });

        //Creates an action event for the add words button
        btnAddWords.addActionListener((ActionEvent a) -> {
            //Finds the source of the button that was clicked
            String strSource = String.valueOf(a.getSource());
            String strSourceCut1 = strSource.substring(25,30);

            //Finds the index of the button that was clicked
            String [] aryIndex = strSourceCut1.split(",");
            String strIndex = aryIndex[0];

            try {
                //Creates a new file reader and buffered reader
                FileReader file_to_read3 = new FileReader(path);
                BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(file_to_read3);

                //Finds the index value
                int intIndex = Integer.parseInt(strIndex)/16;

                //Creates a counter to count line numbers
                int counter = 0;

                while((br3.readLine()) != null) {
                    //Increases counter value by 1
                    counter ++;
                    if(intIndex == 0)
                    {
                        try {
                            //Reads the set and subject for the 
                            String chosenDeck2 = br3.readLine();

                            //Splits the subject from the set
                            String [] aryDeck = chosenDeck2.split(",");
                            chosenDeck = aryDeck[0];

                            //Closes the buffered reader and file reader
                            br3.close();
                            file_to_read3.close();



                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                        }

                    } else if ( counter == intIndex) {
                        String chosenDeck2 = br3.readLine();

                        String [] aryDeck = chosenDeck2.split(",");
                        chosenDeck = aryDeck[0];

                        br3.close();
                        file_to_read3.close();  
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
            //Opens the new words frame
            frmWords s = new frmWords(deckName, newXPoint, newYPoint, chosenDeck);
            s.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    } catch (Exception e ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


    }
```

What I am finding is that when I am deleting the br1.close() the stream closed error stops, but I can find any reason why? Nothing is using that reader, that I can see. And when I do delete it I get and error saying that the test files are being used by other processes, which I can only presume is br1.

I know this may seem confusing to look at, probably because it is sloppy code, but I would really appreciate some help. I am a high school student.

Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like you are closing br2 in a while loop. Depending on if this executed more than once, this could be an issue

Comment: Same with br3 as well

Comment: I'd take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900477/java-io-exception-stream-closed.
Your code would benefit from dividing into functions and trying to reproduce with minimal code to reproduce your issue since your learning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [closable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) feature from Java 7:

```
 try ( FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
              BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file_to_read)){
            //Finds the line number to see the number of cards in each set
            lnr2= new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\priceadria\\Desktop\\Words_" + strSetName + ".txt")));
            lnr2.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            strLineNumber2 = String.valueOf(lnr2.getLineNumber());
            lineNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(strLineNumber2);
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            strLineNumber2 = "0";
        }
```

Then you don't have to care about closing your stream or file in the right order. 
Furthermore you could just use libs for doing the "readFile" job like apache commons or guava.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct nested `Readers` as you do, for example,

> ```
>     FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
>     BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);
> ```

, closing the outer one automatically closes the inner one, too.  You do not need to close the inner one yourself, and if you try to do so after closing the outer one, as you do, you will find that it is already closed.

The best solution is to close only the outer one (as opposed to your workaround of closing only the *inner* one).  You probably don't even need to retain a reference to the inner one -- a more typical idiom would go something like this:

```
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    try {
        // ... manipulate br1 ...
    } finally {
        br1.close();
        // no need to explicitly close the inner FileReader
    }
```

You could write that in try-with-resources form if that suits your fancy.

Similar applies to nested `Writer`s, `InputStream`s, and `OutputStream`s, too.