# 'Stream closed' exception occurs

Tags: java, spring-mvc, io, apache-poi, java-io

Recently i am developing a code to export data to excel.
I used apache POI for developing this functionality.

Please consider the below code.

```
public static void prepareDateForCSVGeneration(List<DataList> dataList,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws CashBookingInquiryServiceApplicationException {

         try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
              XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
              //below method creates headers and rows
              convertToExcel(workbook, dataList);
              response.setContentType("text/vnd.ms-excel");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xlsx");
                workbook.write(out);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.out.println("Exceptin in excel "+exception.getMessage());
                exception.printStackTrace() ;
            }
    }
```

everything works fine, means excel file downloads successfully but after that in console it throws exception :

> ```
> Exceptin in excel Stream is closed
> [err] java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
> [err]     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.outbound.HttpOutputStreamImpl.validate(HttpOutputStreamImpl.java:213)
> [err]     at [internal classes]
> ```

Not sure why this is happening.

i referred [[java IO Exception: Stream Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900477/java-io-exception-stream-closed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa][1])

but i did not find any concrete solution.
Can you please suggest what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code for the method  `convertToExcel(workbook, dataList);`

Comment: The stream is closed in ZipPackage.saveImpl() in the try-with-resources. I have to admit, that this unexpected for user code and we "did it again" ... To workaround, you need to wrap your ServletOutputStream with a class which extends FilterOutputStream and overwrite close() with a no-op method.

Comment: I've fixed this on the trunk,  i.e. the upcoming 4.0.0 version

Comment: kiwiwings, i am not getting your answer.

Comment: Yati, convertToExcel method just prepare data for headers and rows.thats why i have not included it here.