# Updating and encrypting existing xlsx file with Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have existing xlsx spreadsheet. I am using Apache POI 3.17 to read it, add some entries and save as password protected spreadsheet in new file. 
After I run the program, new file is password protected, but I don't see new entries, only the ones which existed before. Here is simplified version of the program which opens empty spreadsheet, writes new cell and saves in new file with password. When I open file in Excel 2010 using password I still see empty spreadsheet. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  try {
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
    enc.confirmPassword("passw");


    File is = new File("./empty.xlsx");
    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(is, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);

    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(opc);

    Sheet sheet  = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("CRYPT");

    OutputStream encos = enc.getDataStream(fs);
    opc.save(encos);
    opc.close();

    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("./f.xlsx"));
    fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
    fos.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in [your mail thread](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Question-Problem-with-Encryption-in-POI-td5730885.html)

Comment: @kiwiwings: Your code fails using `apache poi` version `3.17` while closing `encos`: `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/poifiles/encrypted_package1071788535456667764crypt (...) at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.standard.StandardEncryptor$StandardCipherOutputStream.processPOIFSWriterEvent(StandardEncryptor.java:201) ... at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.standard.StandardEncryptor$StandardCipherOutputStream.close(StandardEncryptor.java:169)`

Comment: @AxelRichter: you are right, I've just tested the code on the trunk and I've changed the closing habbit because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646538). I need to make it more clear in the release notes.

Comment: @kiwiwings: OK. And since you are using a `File` in `Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("empty.xlsx"));`, the `empty.xlsx` is updated too while `wb.write` updates the `OPCPackage`. So after that `empty.xlsx` contains the new value in `B2` too and is not more "empty" ;-). As said in my answer, it lacks  a possibility for programmmatically influencing the committing process between the `XSSFWorkbook` and it's `OPCPackage`.

Comment: I've fixed the closing issue via [#60713](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60713) ... I'll fix the unwanted parallel writing via [#59287](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59287)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the discrepancy in committing changes between the `XSSFWorkbook` and it's `OPCPackage`. Changes in  the `XSSFWorkbook` will be committed to the `OPCPackage` only while `XSSFWorkbook.write`. So if you do not (or cannot) write out the `XSSFWorkbook`, the `OPCPackage` stays unchanged.

On other hand, if you write out the `XSSFWorkbook`, it **always** commits changes to the `OPCPackage` from which the workbook was created. So if that was an `OPCPackage` created from an `File`, then always this file is updated before the workbook will possibly be written into another file. This is annoying too.

So in my opinion it lacks a possibility for programmmatically influencing the committing process between the `XSSFWorkbook` and it's `OPCPackage`.

But the main problem with your code is that you are writing the `OPCPackage`, which is not updated,  to the `Encryptor`'s data stream. Instead you should writing the `Workbook`, which you have updated.

So for example:

```
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelUpdateAndEncrypt {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

  EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
  Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
  enc.confirmPassword("passw");

  FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("./empty.xlsx");
  Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);

  Sheet sheet  = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("CRYPT");

  OutputStream encos = enc.getDataStream(fs);
  wb.write(encos); 
  encos.close();
  wb.close();

  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("./f.xlsx"));
  fs.writeFilesystem(os);
  os.close();

 }
}
```