# java Stream closed exception occurs during File Writer write method

Tags: java, exception, stream

The code which I currently have as below used to write the response and recently i am getting  java.io.IOException: Stream closed error frequently even though I closed the File Writer properly not sure why any body please help me on this.

```
Exception:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:26)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:99)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at com.test.resp.RespWriter.write(RespWriter.java:150)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:213)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:194)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1690)
```

The place I am getting the exception at below place

fileWriter.write(buff, off, len); Here is the place I am getting Exception

```
public void write(char[] buff, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            printWriter.write(buff, off, len);
            if(count < FILE_SIZE) {                
                fileWriter.write(buff, off, len); Here is the place I am getting Exception 
                count+=len;
            }
}
```

Code:

```
public RespWriter(RequestHeader header, PrintWriter printWriter)
 throws InitializationException {
  isClosed = false;
    if(StringUtil.isEmpty(FILE_PATH) || printWriter == null) {
        throw new InitializationException(
            InitializationException.ERR_CODE);
    } else {
        this.header = header;


        File responseFolder = new File(FILE_PATH.concat(
            "/".concat(header.getUserId())));

        boolean dirCreated = responseFolder.mkdir();            

        if(responseFolder.exists() && responseFolder.isDirectory()) {
            responseFile = new File(responseFolder,
                "R"+header.getId()+FILE_EXTENSION);
        } else {
            throw new InitializationException(
                InitializationException.ERR_CODE,
                "response folder does not exist");
        }
    this.printWriter = printWriter;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(responseFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("FileWriter could not be created", e);
        }

        writeHeaderToFile();
    }
}

private void writeHeaderToFile() {
        String headerStr = "\nRequest Header:\nnull\n";
        try {
            if(header!=null) {
                headerStr="\n"+Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    +" Request Header:\n" + header.toString() + "\n";
            }
            fileWriter.write(headerStr, 0, headerStr.length());
            fileWriter.write("Date:");
            fileWriter.write(new Date().toString()+"\n");
            fileWriter.write("Response:\n"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+": ");
            fileWriter.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException occurred writing header to file", e);
        }
}

      @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

        if(!isClosed) {
            try {
                if(fileWriter!=null) {
                    try {
                        fileWriter.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        log.error("IOException", e);
                    }
                }
                if(printWriter!=null) {
                    try {
                        printWriter.close();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        log.error("IOException", e);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                isClosed = true;
            }
        }
}
public void flush() throws IOException {
            if(printWriter!=null) {
                try {
                    printWriter.flush();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    log.error("IOException", e);
                }
            }
            if(fileWriter!=null) {
                try {
                    fileWriter.flush();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    log.error("IOException", e);
                }
            }
}
```

Any thing i missed in the code or do I want to create new FileWriter instance in the Write method. Please help on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The `FileWriter` is closed.  Why you are ignoring exceptions when you create the `FileWriter` is a mystery. What the additional `PrintWriter` is for is another, and why you are closing the `FileWriter` before the `PrintWriter` that is wrapped around it is yet another.

Comment: Hi, I am throwing exception and I didn't paste the code please find below             if(StringUtil.isEmpty(FILE_PATH) || printWriter == null) {
   throw new InitializationException(
    InitializationException.ERR_CODE);
  } The above code is reason to close the PrintWriter

Comment: Do I want to close the FileWriter first and then PrintWriter. Or can I create a new FileWriter instance in the Write method please suggest

Comment: So this isn't the real code. So what exactly is the point?

Comment: This is the real code only but i am getting this place frequently error.

Comment: No, it isn't the real code. You have already admitted that 'I didn't paste the code', and you have already posted a supplement, in comments. You need to post the real code. Otherwise you're just wasting time. I don't care about yours, but mine is valuable.

Comment: @user207421 Updated the current real code

Comment: So the `FileWriter` is still closed. No change here.

Comment: yes so what change I need to do

Comment: Err, don't try to write to your `FileWriter` after you've closed it? Is this such a mystery?

Comment: Not clear can you explain where to write Not that expert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream is already closed when enters the write() method. I would suggest you println 3 different debug statements to spot the issue. 1 when you open/create the streamer, 2 when close it and 3 when you attempt to write to it, so you can see the order of operations. Also, have a look here: [java IO Exception: Stream Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900477/java-io-exception-stream-closed)

Comment: the link you provided is clear but still not sure what change i need to do

Comment: The change needed is to fix the bug :). Sorry but I cannot debug your code. Also in the stacktrace it says about line 150 which I cannot see in the code posted. `com.test.resp.RespWriter.write(RespWriter.java:150)`

Comment: Respwriter is the code attached and the write method also attached