# Second method invocation to read from command line fails with java IO Exception: Stream Closed

Tags: java, ioexception, system.in

I have two consecutive calls to a method that uses a `BufferedReader` over an `InputStreamReader` to read a line of input from the keyboard. These are the two calls -

```
    System.out.println("Enter size of array for hash table...");
    size = getInt();

    System.out.println("Enter initial number of items...");
    numInitial = getInt();
```

The issue is - while the first call works correctly, the second one fails with an exception -

```
Enter size of array for hash table...
12
Enter initial number of items...
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
    at hashing.HashTableApp.getInt(HashTableApp.java:28)
    at hashing.HashTableApp.main(HashTableApp.java:48)
```

These are my method definitions -

```
public static String getString() {
    String s;
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
        s = br.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        s = null;
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return s;   
}

public static int getInt() {
    String s = getString();
    return Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

Looking at the exception message, it looks like the Stream gets closed after the first call to `getInt()`, and then the second call to `getInt()` fails when it tries to read from the command line. However, I'm not sure why this happens. Normally this issue arises when one tries to read from a stream that is already closed, as described previously [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900477/java-io-exception-stream-closed).

However, in my case, the stream closing from the first call shouldn't affect the second, because it's an entirely new method invocation.

For some context, this is pretty much the same code from the [book](https://rineshpk.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/0/1820991/data_structures_and_algorithms_in_javatqw_darksiderg.pdf) I'm reading about Hashing, except the try-with-resources structure.

Comment: You do not want try-with-resources on `System.in` if you want to use it again

Comment: And you also don't want two buffered readers on the same source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Any links to resources where I can read up more on why this is a problem? Because I'm not sure I understand what's happening behind the scenes which leads to this issue.