# Stream is closed in java

Tags: java

This is the code I have

```java
    try
    {
      reader.read(msg1,0,6);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e1){
      loopcount = 1 ;
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
      client.close();
      reader = null;
      writer = null;
      client = null;
    
    }
    try
    {
      msg2 = new char[2000];
      reader.read(msg2,0,intArrLen);
    }catch (SocketTimeoutException e1){
      loopcount = 1 ;
      reader.close();
      writer.close();
      client.close();
      reader = null;
      writer = null;
      client = null;
    
    }
```

Inside the method, at this line reader. read (msg1,0,6) able to read the response correctly. After this when trying to read the response at the line reader. read (msg2,0,intArrLen).

It is giving stream is closed exception - Exception: java. I o. IO Exception: Stream closed. So need help in understanding why this exception is coming.

Comment: might be an issue server side

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are closing the connection of the reader and then without creating a new one calling the function using same reader which is close.

Instead, you can use `reader.flush()` method .

For more information please refer to the  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900477/java-io-exception-stream-closed).

Comment: First time while reading the message using the reader object there is no SocketTimeoutException therefore the reader object is not closed. While using the same reader object to read the message second time we are getting stream is closed exception, when we run the code 10 times, this issue is coming 3 to 4 times. Please help.